# Getting `document.location.href` with Arabic letters

Tags: javascript, html, href, encode, arabic

The problem is that I don't get the `document.location.href` in Arabic letters.

I get it as

`/cat/%D9%81%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA`

instead of:

`/cat/فعاليات`

I'm trying to get the page url and compare it to a list of menu items, so I can determine which item to select.

I'm trying this:

```
var url = document.location.href;

if(url.indexOf('blablabla') > 0 )
{
  ...
}
```

instead of 'blablabla' there will be some Arabic text.

Help Please!
Thank you

Comment: in the urls everything is by default url_encod(); your only option is to replace 'blablabla' with <?php echo url_encode('ARABIC_TEXT'); ?> I think it will do the trick

Comment: Thanks for the fast replay, I'm not using php.. any other ideas ?

Comment: Why are you using Arabic letters to name your folders instead of latin-character transcripts? For example use `events` instead of `فعاليات`. And then your content to be in Arabic. I think even if you fix this here now, you will have more problems in the future.

Comment: actually im using asp.net routing, i get all the data from the database.. i just wanted it to be easy for the users.. so they can access the links directly.

Comment: Is there a public URL we can see this problem on? (It doesn't have to be the one you're working on, just one with Arabic characters in it.)

Comment: you may use the jsfiddle by harikrishnan.n0077 : http://jsfiddle.net/7spmF/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Functions/decodeURIComponent) it decodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component previously created by encodeURIComponent or by a similar routine.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `decodeURIComponent(url);`

**Check this fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7spmF/